# Filter an array of object by nested dynamic object key

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

I would like to filter an array of object by a nested-key.

Here's where I'm stuck:

#### Data

```js
const dataSet = [{
  firstName: {
    value: 'John'
  },
  lastName: {
    value: 'Doe'
  },
}, {
  firstName: {
    value: 'Alicia'
  },
  lastName: {
    value: 'Keys'
  },
}, ];
```

#### Method

```js
const sortData = (sortKey: string, arrayToSort: any[], isASC: boolean) => {
  const compare = (a: any, b: any) => {
    const aValue = String(a[sortKey].value);
    const bValue = String(b[sortKey].value);
    if (isASC) {
      return aValue.localeCompare(bValue, undefined, {
        numeric: isNumeric(aValue),
      });
    }
    return bValue.localeCompare(aValue, undefined, {
      numeric: isNumeric(bValue),
    });
  };
  return [...arrayToSort.sort(compare)];
};

const sortedData = sortData(header, dataSet, true);
```

But it doesn't sort... If I sort by `firstName` in ascending order, I would like to get Alicia first, but John is always coming first xD

Comment: it is working. please check.

Comment: Assuming you pass `header` as "firstName" and that `isNumeric` is something like `(n) => typeof n === 'number'`, this does work. At least for this example: https://jsfiddle.net/4rbpgaL5/

Comment: Ok my bad... That's the worst post ever... Yes it is working... I made changes to my code to post it, and fixed the error xD. But the dom doesn't rerender (I'm using react). but I'll figure it out, thx guys